# replace NAs on one factor with values from another factor

Tags: r, replace, na, factors

There's something very basic I am missing here

```
d <- data.frame(
g0  = c("A", "B", NA, NA, "C", "C"),
g1  = LETTERS[1:6])
d
    g0 g1
1    A  A
2    B  B
3 <NA>  C
4 <NA>  D
5    C  E
6    C  F
```

The I have this code, but it does not work

```
d$g0[is.na(d$g0)] <- d$g1[is.na(d$g0)]
```

Desired result.

```
d
    g0 g1
1    A  A
2    B  B
3    C  C
4    D  D
5    C  E
6    C  F
```

Comment: Thank you @rawr for responding to my question. I tried googling "invalid factor level, NA generated," but I honestly did not understand what was happening. Maybe I should go to bed.

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff, thanks. That's super helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always helpful to remember the original design rationale behind factors. They were intended for categorical variables that took on one of a fixed set of values. So imagine I changed your example slightly to be:

```
d <- data.frame(color  = c("red", "blue", NA, NA, "green", "green"),
                amount  = c("high","low","low","mid","mid","high"))

> d
  color amount
1   red   high
2  blue    low
3  <NA>    low
4  <NA>    mid
5 green    mid
6 green   high
```

Now it totally makes sense that R complains when we run the following:

```
> d$color[is.na(d$color)] <- d$amount[is.na(d$color)]
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(d$color), value = c(3L, 1L, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

because why would we ever want a `color` of "high" or "mid"? That makes no sense. The mental model here is that either two factors really have nothing to do with each other, or if they do, their levels should be the same. So,

```
levels(d$color) <- c(levels(d$color),"low","mid")
d$color[is.na(d$color)] <- d$amount[is.na(d$color)]
```

this runs with no problems:

```
> d
  color amount
1   red   high
2  blue    low
3   low    low
4   mid    mid
5 green    mid
6 green   high
```

even if the result is semantically nonsensical.

Of course, many people find all this factor level juggling irksome and would have simply done:

```
d <- data.frame(color  = c("red", "blue", NA, NA, "green", "green"),
                amount  = c("high","low","low","mid","mid","high"), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and then R won't care what you fill the `NA` values with at all, because they aren't factors anymore.

Comment: Thank you joran, since I am not generating my data, but get it with `factors` I wondered if there is a way to _simply_ convert all `factors` to `chr`? Also, is there a generalized way to use teh level combination where I grab the levels from g1? It's not only two levels in my actual data. This was simply a simple working example. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that the first part of my comment above is answered by [@HaddE.Nuff's comment to my initial question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508897/replace-nas-on-one-factor-with-values-from-another-factor?noredirect=1#comment60624915_36508897).

Comment: @EricFail There are lots of ways. Here's one: `is_f <- sapply(d,is.factor); d[is_f] <- lapply(d[is_f],as.character)`